# vue.js(2) window.scrollY always return 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuestic-admin

I've got some questions about vuejs and router ..

1. window.addEventListener('scroll', ...) also is not detected in my component.
2. When I typed 'window.scrollY' in console.log. It will always return 0 back to me.
3. Right scroll(Y) are available and window.innerHeight is not equal 0
4. I can't detected when client move scroll to bottom
5. I use vuestic and vue-router
   Thank you

```
  created () {
    // Not working because window.scrollY always return 0
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll (event) {}
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is 'window.innerHeight' doesn't increase depend on content's height (dynamic from fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to listen for scrolling a child element.

and using getBoundClientRect:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>navbar</nav>
    <main id="listen">main</main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  created() {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", this.listenScroll);
  },
  destroyed() { // remember to remove the listener when destroy the components
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listenScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    listenScroll() {
      let myScroll = document.querySelector("#listen").getBoundingClientRect()
        .top;
      console.log(myScroll);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
nav {
  height: 100px;
}
main {
  height: 700px;
}
</style>
```

here there is a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hill-x3wb1?file=/src/App.vue:0-560